# How to select the first product variant as a default?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I have products on woocommerce with 5 variants and I am trying to set the first variant as a default so when visitors/customers browse product pages they would see the first variant pre-selected.

I have gone through some of the threads which are not useful anymore.

If anyone could help to get this done with the recent version of woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Woo-commerce option to select default variation in front-end. Please see attached file:
[image: These are the attributes that will be pre-selected on the frontend.]

Comment: I have more than 2K published products and more on the way, so it is a painful job to do it manully.

Looking for a solution to do it through the code, so it could be done for once for all existing and upcoming products.